# How to include javascript code in a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition

I'm trying to add a javascript code into my HTML page however I can't do it. 
I have tried it on fiddle, it works. an example of the working code is like on this link (http://jsfiddle.net/kF2uK/2/).

my html code and javascript is below, could you tell me how to implement it

```js
function buttonState(){
    $("#timeslots").each(function(){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if($(this).val() == "" ) return false;
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', '');
    })
}

$(function(){
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#timeslots').change(buttonState);
})
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 
 <body class="container-fluid"> 
            <div class="container">
                            
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Day *</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="day">
                                        <option selected>Select</option>
                                        <option>Monday</option>
                                        <option>Tuesday</option>
                                        <option>Wednesday</option>
                                        <option>Thursday</option>
                                        <option>Friday</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                        
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Time *</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="timeslots">
                                        <option selected>Select (5 Slots Available)</option>
                                        <option disabled>09.00</option>
                                        <option>10.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>11.00</option>
                                        <option>12.00</option>
                                        <option>13.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>14.00</option>
                                        <option>15.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>16.00</option>
                                        <option>17.00</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
            
        </body>
```

Comment: Where is your `<script>` tag? If you don't have one, well, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML needs a `<script src="pathToJavaScript"></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

put the javascript into a file called myscript.js

```
    // this is myscript.js
    function buttonState(){
    $("#timeslots").each(function(){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        if($(this).val() == "" ) return false;
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', '');
    })
}

$(function(){
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#timeslots').change(buttonState);
})
```

put the html in a different file save it as index.html

```
<!-- this is index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <body class="container-fluid">  
            <div class="container">

                    <form>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Day *</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="day">
                                        <option selected>Select</option>
                                        <option>Monday</option>
                                        <option>Tuesday</option>
                                        <option>Wednesday</option>
                                        <option>Thursday</option>
                                        <option>Friday</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Time *</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="timeslots">
                                        <option selected>Select (5 Slots Available)</option>
                                        <option disabled>09.00</option>
                                        <option>10.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>11.00</option>
                                        <option>12.00</option>
                                        <option>13.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>14.00</option>
                                        <option>15.00</option>
                                        <option disabled>16.00</option>
                                        <option>17.00</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="submit">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>

        </body>
```

in index.html add the script tags just before the body tag closes( A closed body tag looks like this: `</body>`) with the source pointing at your newly created javascript file.

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

however, because you want to use jquery you have to add that script into the html file as well. You can download jquery or use google cdn. It needs to be included before your script tag since your script uses jquery. This example uses the cdn, so it will work, but if you're using jquery in an actual project I would suggest downloading it into your project directory and adding it like you do myscript.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have done exactly like you have mentioned, the problem is, the state of the button doesn't change even after selecting new option from <select> tags.